# Замена символов в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пишу парсер и стоит задача поменять русское название на транслит и все пробелы и другие знаки заменить на - . Но подряд тире должно быть не больше одного.
Пример:

```
Input: Доброе утро, славяне - погромисты!
Output: dobroe-utro--slavyane---pogromisti-
```

Должно быть:

```
Output: dobroe-utro-slavyane-pogromisti-
```

А выдаёт

```
dobroe-utro--slavyane---pogromisti-
```

Подскажите, что можно сделать. Спасибо!
Мой код:

```
def transliterate(name):
    slovar = {'а': 'a', 'б': 'b', 'в': 'v', 'г': 'g', 'д': 'd', 'е': 'e', 'ё': 'yo',
              'ж': 'zh', 'з': 'z', 'и': 'i', 'й': 'i', 'к': 'k', 'л': 'l', 'м': 'm', 'н': 'n',
              'о': 'o', 'п': 'p', 'р': 'r', 'с': 's', 'т': 't', 'у': 'yu', 'ф': 'f', 'х': 'h',
              'ц': 'c', 'ч': 'ch', 'ш': 'sh', 'щ': 'sht', 'ъ': '', 'ы': 'y', 'ь': '', 'э': 'e',
              'ю': 'u', 'я': 'ya', 'А': 'a', 'Б': 'b', 'В': 'v', 'Г': 'g', 'Д': 'd', 'Е': 'e', 'Ё': 'yo',
              'Ж': 'zh', 'З': 'z', 'И': 'i', 'Й': 'yo', 'К': 'k', 'Л': 'l', 'М': 'm', 'Н': 'n',
              'О': 'o', 'П': 'p', 'Р': 'r', 'С': 's', 'Т': 't', 'У': 'u', 'Ф': 'f', 'Х': 'h',
              'Ц': 'c', 'Ч': 'ch', 'Ш': 'sh', 'Щ': 'sht', 'Ъ': '', 'Ы': 'y', 'Ь': '', 'Э': 'E',
              'Ю': 'yu', 'Я': 'ya', 'A': 'а', 'B': 'b', 'V': 'v', 'G': 'g', 'D': 'd', 'E': 'e', 'Z': 'z', 'I': 'i',
              'O': 'o', 'P': 'p', 'R': 'r', 'S': 's', 'T': 't', 'U': 'u', 'F': 'f', 'H': 'h', '" ': '-',
              'C': 'c', 'K': 'k', 'L': 'l', 'M': 'm', ',': '-', '?': '', ' ': '-', 'ґ': '', 'ї': '', 'є': '',
              'Ґ': 'g', 'Ї': 'i', 'Є': 'e', 'N': 'n', ' - ': '-', '/': '-', '\\': '-', 'Ø': '', '"': '',',':'-', '!': '-'}
    for key in slovar:
        name = name.replace(key, slovar[key])
    return name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    transliterate('Доброе утро, славяне - погромисты!')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение через регулярку:

- `-{2,}` -- этот шаблон находят два и более подряд идущих `-`
- `sub` -- делает замену

Пример:

```
import re


def transliterate(name):
    slovar = {
        'а': 'a', 'б': 'b', 'в': 'v', 'г': 'g', 'д': 'd', 'е': 'e', 'ё': 'yo',
          'ж': 'zh', 'з': 'z', 'и': 'i', 'й': 'i', 'к': 'k', 'л': 'l', 'м': 'm', 'н': 'n',
          'о': 'o', 'п': 'p', 'р': 'r', 'с': 's', 'т': 't', 'у': 'yu', 'ф': 'f', 'х': 'h',
          'ц': 'c', 'ч': 'ch', 'ш': 'sh', 'щ': 'sht', 'ъ': '', 'ы': 'y', 'ь': '', 'э': 'e',
          'ю': 'u', 'я': 'ya', 'А': 'a', 'Б': 'b', 'В': 'v', 'Г': 'g', 'Д': 'd', 'Е': 'e', 'Ё': 'yo',
          'Ж': 'zh', 'З': 'z', 'И': 'i', 'Й': 'yo', 'К': 'k', 'Л': 'l', 'М': 'm', 'Н': 'n',
          'О': 'o', 'П': 'p', 'Р': 'r', 'С': 's', 'Т': 't', 'У': 'u', 'Ф': 'f', 'Х': 'h',
          'Ц': 'c', 'Ч': 'ch', 'Ш': 'sh', 'Щ': 'sht', 'Ъ': '', 'Ы': 'y', 'Ь': '', 'Э': 'E',
          'Ю': 'yu', 'Я': 'ya', 'A': 'а', 'B': 'b', 'V': 'v', 'G': 'g', 'D': 'd', 'E': 'e', 'Z': 'z', 'I': 'i',
          'O': 'o', 'P': 'p', 'R': 'r', 'S': 's', 'T': 't', 'U': 'u', 'F': 'f', 'H': 'h', '" ': '-',
          'C': 'c', 'K': 'k', 'L': 'l', 'M': 'm', ',': '-', '?': '', ' ': '-', 'ґ': '', 'ї': '', 'є': '',
          'Ґ': 'g', 'Ї': 'i', 'Є': 'e', 'N': 'n', ' - ': '-', '/': '-', '\\': '-', 'Ø': '', '"': '',',':'-', '!': '-'
    }
    for key in slovar:
        name = name.replace(key, slovar[key])

    name = re.sub('-{2,}', '-', name)
    return name


print(transliterate('Доброе утро, славяне - погромисты!'))
# dobroe-yutro-slavyane-pogromisty-
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно через регулярные выражения их схлопнуть в один.

```
import re

re.sub("-+", "-", "dobroe-utro--slavyane---pogromisti-")
```